# display datatable text

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a data table with many rows and columns.
How can I display the value (text) in row 1 column 1 to a message box?

I am able to display the row count, but can't seem to figure out how to display the actual contents of the cells.

I'm using VS2012, and coding in VB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
MessageBox.Show(datatabelname.rows(1)(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim myDataRow AS DataRow = myDataTable.Rows(0)
MessageBox.Show(myDataRow(0))
```

I think this works as well:

```
myDataTable.Rows(0).Field(Of String)(0)
```

Comment: Note that Rows (and Columns) are 0-based.  So the first row has an index of 0